# Add custom console to Eclipse console list

Tags: eclipse-plugin, console, eclipse-rcp

Based on this [tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F), I'm creating an Eclipse plugin which provides a new console, The console is added to the view and I can print messages there, but for some reason it is not added to the consoles list (the dropdown list in the view's corner, see image below).

This is how I'm creating the console:

```java
public void createConsole(String name) {
    ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
    IConsoleManager consoleManager = plugin.getConsoleManager();

    console = new MessageConsole(name, null);
    consoleManager.addConsoles(new IConsole[]{console});
}
```

And then I can print messages using this method:

```java
public void print(String msg) {
    MessageConsoleStream out = console.newMessageStream();
    out.println(msg);
}
```

Also I'm using this method to bring the console view to the front:

```java
public void bringToFront() {
    try{
        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
        String id = IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW;
        IConsoleView view = (IConsoleView) page.showView(id);
        view.display(console);
    } catch(PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I see you're relatively new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a new *type* of console to the console view, you need to provide a `consoleFactories` extension:

```xml
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleFactories">
   <consoleFactory
         class="com.example.MyConsoleFactory"
         icon="icons/etool16/my-console.png"
         label="My Console">
   </consoleFactory>
</extension>
```

The factory class needs to provide an implementation for `openConsole` in which your console is created and shown, just like you did in your existing code:

```java
class ConsoleFactory implements IConsoleFactory {
  @Override
  public void openConsole() {
    IConsoleManager consoleManager = ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager();
    MyConsole console = new MyConsole();
    consoleManager.addConsoles( new IConsole[] { console } );
    consoleManager.showConsoleView( console );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. One more question, now my new console is displayed but it is located at the bottom of the list (below the "New console view" option), do you know how to relocate the view in the list? I'm checking the docs but they don't mention anything about that:  http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_console_consoleFactories.html

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to influence the position in the drop-down menu.